# Snowflake python connector with Azure AD SSO

Tags: python, azure, single-sign-on, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying python connection to snowflake using snowflake.connector library along with Azure AD SSO authentication. I am using the following code but not sure on the arguments value for Azure AD SSO configuration. I am aware of that for OKTA SSO, we need to put organization okta URL i.e. 'https://companyname.okta.com' for authenticator parameter but not sure of values for Azure AD based SAML SSO configuration. Please let me know if you have any idea to solve this issue

```
ctx = snowflake.connector.connect(
                               user=SNOWFLAKE_USER,
                               password=SNOWFLAKE_PASSWORD,
                               authenticator= '?'
                            )
```

Comment: Did you try `externalbrowser`?

Comment: Second using the externalbrowser or you can setup OAuth too.  Here are the docs on the externalbrowser option: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/admin-security-fed-auth-use.html#browser-based-sso

Answer (score 2):

authenticator=externalbrowser https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/admin-security-fed-auth-use.html#setting-up-browser-based-sso